# Rails rspec with FactoryGirl and instance variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, controller, associations, factory-bot

I do not write tests very well and I have some trouble using instance variable from Application Controller for another controllers in test.
In Rails I had a pretty simple controller action.

```
  def index
    @cities = City.all
    @starred_cities = @cities.where(starred: true)
  end
```

For this action I have a test:

```
RSpec.describe CitiesController, :type => :controller do
  let(:city) { create(:city) }

  describe 'GET #index' do
    let(:cities) { create_list(:city, 2) }
    before { get :index }

    it 'populates an array of all cities' do
      expect(assigns(:cities)).to match_array(cities)
    end

    it 'renders index view' do
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

In application I need to get a country by domain name and set globally for all controllers. I add to ApplicationController before_action method like this:

```
before_action :get_country
def get_country
  country_slugs = {en: 'usa', ru: 'russia', es: 'spain'}
  current_country_slug = country_slugs[I18n.locale]
  @country = Country.find_by_slug(current_country_slug)
end
```

And now I can get cities in my controller only for current country:

```
def index
  @cities = @country.cities
  @starred_cities = @cities.where(starred: true)
end
```

Now I have some trouble because my controller test fails with exception:

```
Failures:

1) CitiesController GET #index populates an array of all cities
  Failure/Error: @cities = @country.cities

  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `cities' for nil:NilClass
   # ./app/controllers/cities_controller.rb:5:in `index'
   # ./spec/controllers/cities_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) CitiesController GET #index renders index view
  Failure/Error: @cities = @country.cities

  NoMethodError:
   undefined method `cities' for nil:NilClass
  # ./app/controllers/cities_controller.rb:5:in `index'
  # ./spec/controllers/cities_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Please help, what should I do to combine such instance variable and make an association on it?

Comment: where is creation of a country? you are getting the exception because of a country is defaulted to nil.

Comment: Where are you initializing `@country`?

Comment: @country comes from the `before_action :get_country`

Comment: @airled it seems like there may be a problem with the line `current_country_slug = country_slugs[I18n.locale]`. can you figure out what `I18n.locale` is returning in the test environment?

Comment: two notes, you should add case when @country becomes undefined... and fix the test to create a default country before test run.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up all associations used in the testcase properly, in your case the country with assigned cities is missing (thus nil.cities is called) or mock the methods to return the objects as AR would return them, like:

```
RSpec.describe CitiesController, :type => :controller do
  describe '#index' do
    let(:cities) { double('cities') }
    let(:starred_cities) { double('starred_cities') }
    let(:country) { double('country', cities: cities) }

    before do
      allow(cities).to receive(:where).with(starred: true).and_return(starred_cities) 
      allow(Country).to receive(:find_by_slug).and_return(country)
      get :index
    end

    it 'populates an array of all cities' do
      expect(assigns(:cities)).to match_array(cities)
    end

    it 'renders index view' do
      expect(response).to render_template :index
    end
  end
end
```

Mocking can be quite usefull if you know what you are doing to prevent hitting the db (slow!) since AR is already quite tested well. But also can let you write passing tests although your implementation has bugs, so use it wisely.

Comment: Ok. Hope it will help